# Clang's libc++: using long long in the definition of std::chrono::duration

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++

In libc++ on 32-bit platforms, `int64_t` is defined as alias of `long long`. On 64-bit platforms: `long`.

On the other hand in definition of `std::chrono::duration` aliases, that you can find [here](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/chrono) `long long` is carelessly used:

```
typedef duration<long long,         nano> nanoseconds;
typedef duration<long long,        micro> microseconds;
typedef duration<long long,        milli> milliseconds;
typedef duration<long long              > seconds;
typedef duration<     long, ratio<  60> > minutes;
typedef duration<     long, ratio<3600> > hours;
```

So for example, when I require type that is strictly 8 bytes long, I would expect

```
  foo(uint64_t);
  foo(int64_t);
```

to be a fairly portable solution. But in case of libc++'s `chrono` it is not true. There is no portable way except to write your own logic similar to `<cstdint>`. Ie, defining two additional definitions of `foo` that take `long long` and `unsigned long long`.

Or another example:

```
  foo(int8_t);
  foo(int16_t);
  foo(int32_t);
  foo(int64_t);
```

Calling `foo(duration.count())` would be ambiguous in this case.

So what the point of using `long long` that is not larger than `long` but it's rank is greater than `long` so it cannot be implicitly cast?

Is this an oversight by developers of `libc++`?

The reason I brought this up is because drivers of **mongodb** won't compile on x64 FreeBSD installation. And the reason looks rather silly. For example, **gcc** used `int64_t` in the definitions of `std::chrono::duration` and so it compiles, as expected.

Comment: There are 64-bit platforms where `long` is 32 bits. Check the difference between LP64 and LLP64 platforms. Note that this is even compiler-specific, not only to the platform, although certain conventions usually exist.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt of course there is, but what this has to do this the question? Library defines `<cstdint>`, so why not use it for portability of another parts of said library?

Comment: My point is that you leading sentence is both wrong and, provided I understand your problem, completely irrelevant! Doesn't it boil down to the question "Why is `duration` defined with `uint64_t` on one platform and `long long` on another?" BTW: Do you have a link for the mongodb build issues?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Issue would be reported soon. The real question is why developers of libc++  make life of the user of library a bit harder.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: @Galik whether this is an oversight or whether there is a specific reason for decision made by developers of libc++.

Answer (score 5):

The standard only requires that `seconds` is a typedef for `duration` with a ratio of 1 and a "signed integer type of at least 35 bits". So libc++'s implementation is correct.

While using `int64_t` would have eased portability in your specific case, that would only carry you so far. MSVC also uses `long long`, not `int64_t`. (Though in that case, those are the same type.) The standard doesn't guarantee `int64_t` for the durations, so relying on it isn't portable even if one more implementation uses it.

The problem here is not that libc++'s implementation does something bad. The problem is that C++'s integer types are somewhat screwy, and though the `intNN_t` types are convenient, they do not completely free you from knowing about the underlying types. In particular, trying to do a complete overload set as your presented for `foo` with those typedefs is just wrong; you need to go for the underlying types precisely because of the problem you encountered: the overload set may or may not cover `long long`, and you will eventually run into that type. That it happened with libc++'s `duration` typedefs instead of some other situation is just coincidence.

Yes, it's a bad situation, but this particular issue is just a small symptom of the larger issue.

Comment: Agree with you completely on the issue of integer type system. Thanks to `C` it's totally screwed. On the other hand, you would expect more consciousness from developers of such progressive library :(

Answer (score 2):

I can speak with some authority on this question as I was the one who wrote this code.  Though the other two answers are very good, and I've upvoted them.

Yes, I did give some thought to these types, and considered defining them in terms of the `int_t*` `typedef`s.

I chose `long long` for those reps that had to be more than 32 bits, and `long` for the rest.  The latter was done with the knowledge that `long` would change from 32 bits to 64 bits when changing the target from i386 to x86_64.

Had I instead used the `int_t*` `typedef`s it is quite possible that others would have complained about ambiguity problems (say between `foo(int)` and `foo(long long)`) with that design as well.  It is difficult to please *everyone*.

I note that in the **mongodb** header mongo/src/mongo/util/time_support.h it says:

```
using Microseconds = stdx::chrono::microseconds;
using Milliseconds = stdx::chrono::milliseconds;
using Seconds = stdx::chrono::seconds;
using Minutes = stdx::chrono::minutes;
using Hours = stdx::chrono::hours;
```

This could just as easily look like:

```
using Microseconds = stdx::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, stdx::chrono::microseconds::period>;
using Milliseconds = stdx::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, stdx::chrono::milliseconds::period>;
using Seconds = stdx::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, stdx::chrono::seconds::period>;
using Minutes = stdx::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, stdx::chrono::minutes::period>;
using Hours = stdx::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, stdx::chrono::hours::period>;
```

I.e. the `<chrono>` library makes it very easy for clients to create custom units.  It sounds like this might be a good solution for **mongodb**.

Comment: My argument is this: in C++11 committee, I want to strongly believe, made a small step to fix portability issues with different sizes of certain integer types on different platforms by adopting `<cstdint>`. It's unusual to see implementation of the very library itself not using introduced types for the same reason: portability.

Answer (score 1):

The standard doesn't require a particular integer type for the representation of the duration.  It does require that the type is available as the `rep` member type, so you can use (e.g.) `std::chrono::duration::seconds::rep` as a type suitable for storing values in seconds.